# AWS API Gateway xml request

Tags: api, aws-api-gateway

I have a question about using API Gateway passing an XML request.  I'm trying to determine how to create a model (schema validation) if the incoming request is in XML rather than JSON. Everything I've found thus far that describes how to create a model is doing so against a JSON request. It also seems when creating a model it's done so using JSON.  Is it possible to create a model for an incoming XML request? I've seen many threads that states you can pass XML request using pass-through when adding the below snippet as the mapping template in the Integration request, but I'm trying to determine how to create a model when the request is XML.  Has anyone here done this before?

```
{
"body" : $input.json('$')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently request validation and models only support JSON as they are written in JSON schema.

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected as much but wanted conformation.  The service I'm working with passes the request as xml and expects xml back.

Comment: What I'm attempting to do is build a model for the service so to be able to export it's swagger definitions, but unfortunately as you mention I can’t build a model because the API Gateway currently only supports JSON for schema/model validation.  Now the mapping portion allows me to wrap the xml in JSON to pass to the lambda (i.e. "body" : $input.json('$')).  At the end of the day all I was attempting to do is export the swagger definitions with the intention to build an API portal.  I guess I could build the swagger definitions by hand in such cases.